# Has superset functionality changed?

Tags: django, apache-superset

I've been using Django and superset in docker containers. I had these two lines of codes

```
    <div class="container">
    <a target="_blank" href="http://localhost:8088/login?username={{ username }}&redirect=/superset/dashboard/services/?standalone=0&expand_filters=0">Explore Dataset</a>
</div>

<div>
    <iframe src="http://localhost:8088/login?username={{ username }}&redirect=/superset/dashboard/services/?standalone=&show_filters=1" style="position:absolute;top:220px;bottom:0px;width:100%;height:100%"></iframe>
</div>
```

Up until last week they have both worked. The first one to function as a link to the actual superset page and the iframe to show a specific dashboard on the page.

I rebuilt my containers last week and now my iframe doesn't work. It shows 'localhost refused to connect.' The other link, however, does work still. Is anyone aware of a change in superset (or Django) and a possible fix or workaround to get this working again?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like apache has rolled out a new version that handles this differently. Reverting to version 2.1 maintains the current behavior.